# vertically center a link to an image in a div

Tags: html, css, centering

I would like to vertically center an image (which is also a link) inside the 'left' div.

```css
a {
  outline: 0;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="left.png">
        <img src="left.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note 1: in my real page, the width/height of .main is not known.

Note 2: I have removed all my attempts of centering in the above code to not add confusion :-)

Note 3: I have tested many things found on the web, but none of them works in my case.

Comment: "I have tested many things found on the web, but none of them works in my case." - Many of the things found on the web actually work.  Explain why they don't apply to your situation.

Comment: All the solutions found on the web did not move the image to the center.It is probably because of the context of the image (position/display attributes in the css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vertically center the link in `.left` with your existing markup/css by absolutely positioning the link within `.left` at `top: 50%`, then use `translateY(-50%)` to move it back up 50% of it's own height so it's truly vertically centered.

```
.left a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
a{
  outline:0;
}
.main{
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
.left {
  position:absolute;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
}

.left a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="left.png">
        <img src="https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg">
      </a>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! I was quite close during my attempts, but it did not work :-(

Comment: @LaurentD. fyi this is a good article on centering stuff https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: thanks for the link. It is always surprising how difficult it is to find a solution to your problem by your-self, and how simple it looks at the end :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
.left{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: make sure to remove the `height:100%` on the child element

Comment: There is no such thing in styles written.

Comment: My bad, thought you flexed `.main`. 